# Find inflection points of parametric equations

Tags: calculus

My question is :

How to find **inflection points of parametric equations**? For example consider these parametric polynomial equations:

$X(t) = a_n t^n + ... + a_1t+a_0$, $Y(t) = b_nt^n + ... + b_1t+b_0$

and *t* belongs to [$\alpha$    ,  $\beta$].

I would appreciated if your answers in detail, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing $(X',Y')\neq (0,0)$ (where it's not true the curve may be non-smooth): inflection means that the acceleration vector $(X'',Y'')$ moves from one side of the tangen vector $(X',Y')$ to the other side. When it happens, $(X'',Y'')$ is a multiple of $(X',Y')$. and that's iff $f(t):=X''Y'-Y''X'=0$. To make sure that a $t_0$ such that $f(t_0)=0$ is actually an inflection point, you need to check that $f$ changes its sign at $t_0$. One way to check is that $f'(t_0)\neq0$; sometimes this condition is required in the definition of an inflection point (otherwise, find the first $k$ such that the $k$th derivative of $f$ is non-0 at $t_0$, and check that $k$ is odd).

Comment: Could you explain why "(X′′,Y′′) is a multiple of (X′,Y′) iff f(t):=X′′Y′−Y′′X′=0" ?

Comment: @Zia If it is a multiple then I guess you see that $X''Y'=Y''X'$. To see the other implication - try to prove it directly, or use the fact that $f$ is a determinant if you know what it is (btw $f$ is (up to a sign) the area of the parallelogram with the sides $(X',Y')$ and $(X'',Y'')$)

Comment: > Could you explain ... The first and second derivative vectors are parallel iff their vector cross product is zero. The expression $X''Y' - Y''X'$ is the z-component of this cross product.

Comment: And this expression is also the numerator in the formula for the curvature of a 2D planar curve. So, we're finding places where the curvature changes sign. That's another definition of "inflection".

Answer (score 2):

As explained on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Signed_curvature), the (signed) curvature $k$ of a 2D parametric curve is given by the formula
$$
k = \frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y} - \ddot{x}\dot{y}}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}}
$$
An inflection point is a place where this curvature changes sign. So, to find inflections, we need to find places where $f= \dot{x}\ddot{y} - \ddot{x}\dot{y}$ changes sign. A good start is to find places where $f =0$. In your case, $f$ will be a polynomial of degree $2n-3$, so you'll probably need to use numerical methods.

If you're specifically interested in polynomial curves, it's usually easier to understand geometric properties (like curvature and inflections) if you write the curve in Bezier-Bernstein form, rather than in "power" form. Further info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Comment: Thanks for helpful suggestion.

Comment: Where did you find this definition? Wikipedia provides no citation for it. By your definition, it would be easy to write a parameterization of $y=x^2$ with infinitely many inflection points (say $x(t)=t\sin(t)$). If you are going to call it a geometry property, you had better change your definition. Perhaps you meant to impose conditions on the parameterization.